# derivative of fourier transform

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f\in C^k$ and $f^{(k)}$ be absolutely integrable. I want to show for the fourier transform: 
$$\widehat{f^{(k)}}(z)=(iz)^k\widehat{f}(z)$$

I want to prove it for $k=1$ and did the following:

partial integration:  $$\begin{align*}
\int_a^bf'(w)\exp(-iwz)dw&=f(b)\exp(-ibz)-f(a)\exp(-iaz)+iz\int_a^b f(w)\exp(-iwz)dw
\end{align*}$$

The last term for $a,b\rightarrow\infty$ is the fourier transform of $f(z)$.

But why are $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}f(b)=0$ and the same for $a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that:

> If $|f|$ and $|f'|$ are both integrable, then $f$ must vanish at infinity.

Notice your question pre-suppose that the Fourier transform for $f$ and $f'$ exist, hence they are both integrable. Now 
$$
\int^{\infty}_0 f'(w) \,dw = \lim_{b\to \infty}f(b) - f(0).
$$ 
By integrability of $f'$, the limit exists. Moreover by integrability of $f$, the only possible limit is $0$. The same argument applies for $-\infty$.

Comment: but if $|f|$ is integrable, the fourier transform exists since $\left|\int_{\mathbb R}f(w)\exp(-iwz)dw\right|\leq\int_{\mathbb R}|f(w)|dw<\infty$, doesn't it?

Comment: @jul8.  It does. If you meant to say Parseval's theorem, the isometry between time domain and frequency domain is under $L^2$-norm.